# Deleting demo rows in a 2sxc list (2sxc 8.5.6)

Tags: 2sxc

If a blank demo row (denoted as (0)), gets created in a list by mistake you are able to see it in the 'Manage content-item lists' window, but they have no edit icon or any way to delete them. Is there another way to get rid of these extra unwanted items? they also don't show in the admin area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see it is because it doesn't really exist yet. It's just a slot / placeholder. So there is no item.

Basically you should only have this in situations where you have list-enabled, hit the round (+) for add another placeholder-item. I believe the (-) is missing on the first item, because that could cause side-effects.

There is a way to go into advanced admin to remove it, but it's hard as this is not a normal thing to do - when you have a list, you usually want to add content. 
Since you have not added any data yet, I would simply remove the module and add another one - that's easier than going the advanced admin.

Comment: They get created when a user uses the Add Item in the action menu. The issue then is that if you go to reorder the list there are a bunch of rows in there with nothing in them which is messy. You used to be able to edit them and utilize them or delete them from the list but this is no longer possible. It would be better to get rid of the Add Item function from tbe action menu as no longer seems to have a useful function.

Comment: @Andrew that does make sense. BTW: the reason you're not seeing them inline for "utilizing" them is because you probably didn't specify a demo item. That would appear on each row with the null-item.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much @iJungleBoy appreciate the time taken to answer my questions.